# Join Query - If join table order changes

Tags: sql, join, outer-join

Query1:

```
select * from t1 inner join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
                   left join t4 on t2.id = t4.id
                   left join t3 on t2.id = t3.id
```

Query2:

```
select * from t1 inner join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
                   left join t3 on t2.id = t3.id
                   left join t4 on t2.id = t4.id
```

**Result from Query1 and Query2 will be same or not?**

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: Please revisit your question

Comment: You will get the same rows. But you did not specify an ORDER BY clause, so the engine may order those rows differently.

Comment: do the fact the join condtion remanin the same and overall  you have not relation between the change  in this case the e query are the same .. the result could  change (in your case) if you exchange change t1 and t2

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful when comparing joins with different `join` orders.  If the joins are all inner joins, then the order doesn't matter.  You examples have outer joins.

from t1 inner join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.id left join
     t4
     on t2.id = t4.id left join
     t3
     on t2.id = t3.id

```
from t1 inner join
     t2
     on t1.id = t2.id left join
     t3
     on t2.id = t3.id left join
     t4
     on t2.id = t4.id
```

In this case, the conditions for the two joins are independent of each other.  That is, `t3` and `t4` are only being compared to `t2` which occurs earlier.  The order of the joins is not going to make a difference to the result set.

When you are considering if the result set is the same, you need to consider the following (at least):

- Are any of the join keys `NULL`?
- Are columns being selected from all the tables?
- Are there matches for all join conditions?
- Have the joins changed from left to right?
- Are there parentheses in the `FROM` clause?

There can be surprising (but subtle) differences for queries that look very similar.